# asp:Repeater within asp:Content

Tags: asp.net

I have the following piece of code:

```
<asp:Content id="Content1" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderPageDescription">
            <table class="custom-table">
                    <asp:Repeater ID="oRepeater" runat="server" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr onclick="javascript:location.href='/nuovoTema/viewIdea.aspx?ID='">
                                <td><%# ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem)["ID"] %></td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>     
            </table>            
</asp:Content>
```

The compiler complains that `In content pages, content is not allowed outside <script> or <asp:Content> regions`.

How can I use asp:Content and asp:Repeater together? I have a list to display.

Thanks

Comment: That's correct, you can't place anything outside the Content Place Holders.  But according to this, you don't have anything outside of them, so what's the problem?

Comment: Can you post more of the code from this page? You shouldn't see that error unless you actually have content outside the <asp:content...> control.

Comment: Definitely need more of the page to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like the error is in the part of the page that you posted. Typically this pops up when you either attempt to place content outside of an asp:content block while in a web content page, or b) have some sort of markup error - lack of a closing tag or similiar - that makes the parser *think* that you're placing code outside of a content block.

Check your tags to make sure everything that needs to be closed is, in fact, closed. A good way to start is to simply delete everything inside of the content block - well, copy it somewhere - and see if the page still complains. (You'll probably get errors in the code behind).